# user_signed_in? is always true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, session-cookies

I have no user in my db
I have a rails3 application with devise. No change from default installation, but I have this strange problem:

```
<h1>Home</h1>
<% if (user_signed_in?) %>
  <%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>. 
<% end %>
```

Is always true. Also with no user and with no logged user. What could it be ????

Comment: Are your tests passing? Try it with a different browser.

Comment: LOL. bad for business

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use current_user instead

```
<h1>Home</h1>
<% if current_user %>
  <%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>. 
<% end %>
```

Comment: it's very strange Mikhail, because I've the error again

if I puts 

<% puts "current_user #{current_user.inspect}"%>


I have 

    current_user []

Comment: It seems you have your own helper `current_user`. Go throughout your helpers and see if you have it

Comment: I would not recommend using `current_user` to check if someone is signed in. `current_user` makes a call to the database whereas `user_signed_in? only checks the session. Unless you need the current_user object that's not the way to go.

Comment: yes my test passing but I have error again... I'll investigate deeper